# How to do Erlang-style pattern matching in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I've seen that you can do Erlang-style pattern matching in Matlab *sometimes*.

This for instance, works:

```
[a, b] = size([2, 3])

a = 
     1
b = 
     2
```

Whereas this doesn't:

```
[a, b] = [2, 3]
Too many output arguments.
```

What form does the output have to have in order to get the following result?

```
[a, b] = [2, 3]

a = 
     2
b = 
     3
```

Comment: You gotta [`deal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) with it.

Comment: @Divakar Write this in an answer and include an example so that I can accept it instead!

Comment: It would be a duplicate case. Have seen it before. So, we gotta close it  rather :)

Comment: @Divakar: I don't think deal is what QA wants. It assigns `a=[2 3]` and `b=[2 3]` but I think `a=2` `b=3` is requested.

Comment: Ah yes, I should amend the question with my expected output. Thanks @Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an assignment `[a, b] =` the right hand side must be a [comma separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html), not an array. Unfortunately there is no way to directly do this with an array, you first have to convert it to a cell.

Minimal example using a cell:

```
x={2,3};
[a, b]=x{:};
```

Minimal example starting with an array:

```
x=[2,3];
x=num2cell(x);
[a, b]=x{:};
```